# Invalid project file format Nunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a strange error that just recently started to occur. When trying to open a C# class library project in [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) it immediately throws an exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException...
at NUnit.Util.VSProject.LoadMSBuildProject(String projectDirectory, XmlDocument doc)
at NUnit.Util.VSProject.LoadProject(String projectDirectory, XmlDocument doc)
at NUnit.Util.VSProject.Load()

System.ArgumentException...
at NUnit.Util.VSProject.ThrowInvalidFormat(String projectPath, Exception e)
at NUnit.Util.VSProject.Load()
at NUnit.Util.VSProject..ctor(String projectPath)
at NUnit.Util.ProjectConverters.VisualStudioConverter.ConvertFrom(String path)
at NUnit.Util.ProjectService.ConvertFrom(String path)
at NUnit.Util.ProjectService.LoadProject(String path)
at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadProject(String filePath, String configName)
```

We can load the DLL file directly and run the tests fine, but I am not sure why, when trying to load the .csproj file, it causes this crash.

I use:

**NUnit 2.5.0**

**C# Class Library .NET 3.5**

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem is with having too many "." in a project name.

Nunit barfs if you have

*Name.Project.Something.SometingElse.csproj*

it likes

*Name.project.something.csproj*